# What is ondelete in angularjs directive definition?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading [this article](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/angularjs-collaboration-board-socketio-2132885) and then encountered the ondelete concept in directive, which I couldn't find the explanation in [official document](https://angularjs.org/).

```
app.directive('stickyNote', function(socket) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {};
  var controller = function($scope) {};
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: linker, 
    controller: controller, 
    scope: { 
      note: '=',
      ondelete: '&' // What is ondelete? Where is document? 
    }
  };
});
```

Can you please help me find the official document to explain ondelete in directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope has a [$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) event. You may subscribe on it

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This section of the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) explains what are the different ways of binding scope variables inside a directive to the parent scope.

What that code is doing is a two-way binding with the parent scope variable passed in `stickyNote ondelete` property

Comment: I couldn't find 'ondelete' word on the link page that you provided.

Comment: if you look closely in the link you provided, the `ondelete` is simply another attribute of the directive, it isn't a special keyword and it isn't related to the lifecycle of the scope, it simply is used to declare an isolated scope and how it relates to the value passed into the directive.